# SFTP libraries for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sftp

Are there any good SFTP libraries other than libssh2?? I'm especially looking for a library that is very easy to integrate and manage! As libssh2 is completely written in C, I find adding extensions to the existing code base rather difficult!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are some Objective-C wrappers for libssh2 on GitHub:

- [NMSSH](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH) by Lejdborg (personally, this is my favourite. Super easy to use and well documented)
- [libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper](https://github.com/karelia/libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper) by karelia
- [DLSFTPClient](https://github.com/Leehro/DLSFTPClient) - by Leehro

And some more... These are the most popular ones.

Comment: Does any of these has Resuming the failed upload feature from where it stops?

Comment: NMSSH is great. There's some finicky parts, but Lejdborg is pretty good about getting back if you run into bug(s)

Comment: DLSFTPClient is nice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing using Swift, below wrapper libraries can be used.

- [SwiftSH](https://github.com/Frugghi/SwiftSH) - A Swift SSH framework that wraps libssh2.