# iOS - SimpleFTP How to use SFTP (ssh)?

Tags: ios, ssh, sftp, nsstream

I am trying to use Apple's code from their SimpleFTPSample project to upload/list directory in my app. I am able to get it working on a server using just FTP, but I need it to now work on a server that requires SFTP logins.
Is there a way to set the NSStream to use 'SFTP' when connecting?

Here is Apple's project example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/simpleftpsample/introduction/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

FTP and SFTP are very different protocols.  Have a look at https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit - this is a library that supports ftp, sftp and webdav transfers

Ooops! I missed where the iOS bit wasn't ready yet!  Perhaps the libraries in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462257/sftp-libraries-for-iphone) will help