# How to make FTPS connection in ios

Tags: ios, security, ftps, cfftp

How do I connect to FTP server over TLS? I want to make FTPS connection to FTP server, so that username and password are encrypted. I am unable to find any API for this. I have used `GetController/ PutController` classes in `SimpleFTPSample` provided in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: I think you mean SFTP and not FTPS, no?

Answer (score 0):

**BlackRaccoon is a open source library for doing FTP transfers.**

https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon

Answer (score 0):

Check the thread hopefully solve your problem.
[SFTP libraries for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462257/sftp-libraries-for-iphone)